# MVC - Business Objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I know this has been sort of answered  in various posts, but using `VS2012` with `MVC4`, I wonder if there is a more updated method or new ways to do things.

I have a large enterprise application that has 22 projects in it. It has a complex large business object/logic project and has multiple presentation layers. Working on a new presentation layer using `MVC 4`. I have never used `MVC` before at this scale.

Here are my questions:

1. How do people handle the model  in this scenario? All the Microsoft examples are so simple.
2. I have seen posts to auto mappers and recommend deves use simple models and extract from the BO layer, but some of these tools like auto mapper seem to have gone idle, is there a library in `MVC` that does that now?

I'm just trying to figure out best practices before I get started, seems usually I figure them out after the fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I break my MVC apps into several different projects.

- AppName.Configuration: to handle any configuration of the app (i.e. pulling in web.config/app settings, etc)
- AppName.Data: this is the data layer where all DB access is performed (no business logic).  The DBML/EDMX lives here, my repository class(es) live here as well.
- AppName.Models: this is where all of my ViewModels are defined for MVC, as well as other model objects needed throughout the application.
- AppName.Services: This is my business layer, all everything must pass through here to get to the data layer or to the presentation layer.  ViewModels are constructed from the database objects, data validation happens here, etc.
- AppName.Web: this would be the MVC application.
- AppName.Data.Test: Unit tests for Data app
- AppName.Services.Test: Unit tests for the services
- AppName.Web.Test: Unit tests for the MVC controllers
- AppName.Web.UI.Test: Unit tests for the web user interfaces (using  WATIN)

I don't use any auto-mappers, as i clearly define a specific viewmodel for each view of the application.  If it isn't needed for the view, it doesn't go in there.

Most MVC examples are so basic, they show everything in the web app (data, models, business logic in the controllers, etc.)

I hope this helps.

Comment: I really appreciate the advice; we have most of these layers in other projects. Sounds like the best thing for me to do might be to either make a new project for view models only. Or simply add a folder to our current BO project with view models to be used by any MVC application.  I also need to add a project for controller testing, thanks for including that in your example. I hope we see a few more answers, would be curious to see what others think.